# How do I block multiple users on MediaWiki?

Tags: spam, mediawiki

My wiki collected a lot of spam over the past few months, so I've blocked it to only registered users. Unfortunately I never turned off user registration.
Is it possible to block a lot of user accounts at once, or should I just restart?

Comment: Do you mean delete the user accounts?

Comment: That would work for me. I think MediaWiki may philosophically be designed to favor blocking over deletion.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and least invasive way to prevent a big list of registered users from making modifications is probably to do a bulk password change for the unwelcome users.

Assuming you're running a Unix-like, and that the list of folks you want to *keep* is relatively low:

- [Disable anonymous viewing and/or editing.](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Simple_private_wiki) (which it sounds like you've already done?)
- Dump a list of users from the database to a file.

eg., for MySQL:

```
mysql -p -u root -B wikidb -e 'select user_name from user;' | tee user.list
```

- **Remove the users you want to keep from the user.list file.**
- Use the MediaWiki password command-line tool to change passwords to something random.

eg.

```
cd [wiki-docroot]/maintenance/
while read wikiuser; do 
    echo $wikiuser; 
    php ./changePassword.php $wikiuser BOGUS%PASSblahblah77; 
done <user.list
```

Generating a different password for each user is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: Interesting way to do it. It's very cool to see how flexible shell scripts can be. EDIT: found it, a list of command line tools is here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Maintenance_scripts

Comment: Yep, a nice list of command-line tools there.  Too bad there isn't a bulk password changer among them.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your mysql server:

```
mysql -h DBSERVER_HOST -u wikiuser wikidb -p
```

Enter your password at the prompt.
Once in mysql prompt, search for the user

```
mysql> select user_id,user_name from user;

+---------+------------+
| user_id | user_name  |
+---------+------------+
|       9 | spammer    |
|       7 | r2d2       |
|       1 | admin      |
+---------+------------+
```

Delete every "user_id" you need with:

```
mysql> delete from user where user_id in(7,9);
```